# Material UI define in themes tabs indicatorColor and textColor

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I have a Tabs component:

import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';

```
<Tabs
 value={value}
 indicatorColor="secondary"
 textColor="secondary"
 onChange={handleChange}
 aria-label="status window tabs"
 style={{ minHeight: 32, padding: 0 }}
>
  <Tab value="tab1" label="tab1" sx={tabStyle} />
  <Tab value="tab2" label="tab2" sx={tabStyle} />
  <Tab value="tab3" label="tab3" sx={tabStyle} />
</Tabs>
```

In this snippet the colors for the indicator and text are defined based on the palette colors in the used them.

```
 createTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: amber,
          secondary: red,
        },
        components: {
        // MuiTabs: {
        ?????
          // }
})
```

Instead of using the primary and/or secondary colors I would like to define specific colors for the text and indicator in the tab.
How can they be defined in the theme?

Comment: related to (did not had an answer yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956626/material-ui-tabs-change-text-color-of-selected-tab-by-overriding-default-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete styling solution for styling the `Tabs` and `Tab` components for the `selected` indicator, `default` colour, `hover`,  and `selected` colour, You should be able to do it in this way in your components object in your theme:

```
components: {
  MuiTabs: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '& .MuiTabs-indicator': {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  MuiTab: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        color: 'green',
        '&.Mui-selected': {
          color: 'red',
        },
        '&:hover': {
          color: 'orange',
        },
      },
    }
  },
}
```

Please replace the placeholder colours with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Import `red` & `amber` color from `@mui/material/colors` in your component.

```
...
import { amber, red } from '@mui/material/colors';

createTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: amber,
          secondary: red,
        },
        components: {
        // MuiTabs: {
        ?????
          // }
})
```